# How to align options one under the other?

Tags: html, css

This is the problem.

[image]

I want those `Mobile` and `brand names` one under the other.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.Heading {
  font-family: tahoma;
  width: auto;
  height: 190px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.Nav {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 390px;
  list-style: none;
  .
}

body {
  background: url("IMG2.jpg")no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 3.5%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .6;
  color: white;
  height: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  margin-right: 2px;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  width: 150%;
  height: 900%;
  background: grey;
  opacity: .9;
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: cursive;
  float: left;
  text-align: cente
}

#M {
  padding-top: 15%;
  padding-right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gadgets.info</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="P2CSS.css">

  <body>
    <div class="Heading">
      <h1><u>
  Gadgets</u> <u>Info
   </u> </h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Mobiles
          <div id="M">
            <ul>
              <li>Android</li>
              <li>Windows</li>
              <li>iOS</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          Laptops
          <ul>
            <li>i3</li>
            <li>i5</li>
            <li>i7</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Speakers
          <ul>
            <li>Bluetooth</li>
            <li>Wired</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Others
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</head>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "one down the other"? Can you make a diagram of what you'd like to see?

Comment: i want a drop-down menu like this   https://imgur.com/a/FgKxk

Comment: It looks like you're close. What specifically is going wrong? Incidentally, `<body>` should not be inside of `<head>`; they should be siblings.

Comment: are you trying to create your own? Why not use the bootstrap version and save time? They have similar layouts if that's what you are going for

Comment: is using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/) not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Just apply some css to sub-menu like my snippet

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.Heading {
  font-family: tahoma;
  width: auto;
  height: 190px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.Nav {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 390px;
  list-style: none;
  .
}

body {
  background: url("IMG2.jpg")no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 3.5%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .6;
  color: white;
  height: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  margin-right: 2px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

ul li ul li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900%;
  background: grey;
  opacity: .9;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: cursive;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}

#M {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-right: 30%;
}

ul.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gadgets.info</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="P2CSS.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Heading">
    <h1><u>
  Gadgets</u> <u>Info
   </u> </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Mobiles
        <div id="M">
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Android</li>
            <li>Windows</li>
            <li>iOS</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        Laptops
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>i3</li>
          <li>i5</li>
          <li>i7</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Speakers
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>Bluetooth</li>
          <li>Wired</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Others
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not good...there is still lot of overlap between `mobiles` and `laptops`! :)

Comment: It is because of width of that `.submenu` is large i.e. `width:150%;`

Comment: It is better to give some explanation about what changes you did.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake @Suresh Ponnukalai

Comment: @nidhi no need of sorry. your explanation will help others to understand the changes you did to work it out. Also a post without having any explanation, it can treat as a low quality post. someone can give the down vote also.

Comment: I have changed some css of  `ul li ul li `  that is `width:100%;padding: 0;font-size: large;` so that `.submenu` not overflows from its parent div   please check

Answer (score 0):

Change right: 0; will also resolve problem.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.Heading {
  font-family: tahoma;
  width: auto;
  height: 190px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.Nav {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 390px;
  list-style: none;
  .
}

body {
  background: url("IMG2.jpg")no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 3.5%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .6;
  color: white;
  height: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  margin-right: 2px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

ul li ul li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900%;
  background: grey;
  opacity: .9;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: cursive;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}

#M {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-right: 30%;
}

ul.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gadgets.info</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="P2CSS.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Heading">
    <h1><u>
          Gadgets</u> <u>Info
           </u> </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Mobiles
        <div id="M">
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Android</li>
            <li>Windows</li>
            <li>iOS</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        Laptops
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>i3</li>
          <li>i5</li>
          <li>i7</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Speakers
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>Bluetooth</li>
          <li>Wired</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Others
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```